# Target particular section of href address without jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, href

## Firstly,

Is there a way to target a particular section of a `href` link for use in an `if` statement?

Essentially how can I target the **C** section of the following `href` link:

```
href="/a/b/c/d/e/index.html";
```

## Secondly,

**The desired `if` statement in JavaScript, best described in words, is:**

"If section three contains **C**, *do something*."

## Lastly,

I want to apply the `if` statement using the `href` of each `div` for the `HTML` shown below in order to add to the `classList` of **sample**:

```
<div class="a-1" href="/a/b/c/d/e/index.html">
 <a class="location">text</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try with `split()` to generate an array to match the character at specific position:

```js
var href="/a/b/c/d/e/index.html";
href = href.split('/');
if(href.indexOf('c') == 3){
  console.log('Matched at position:', href.indexOf('c'));
}
```

However, if you wish to implement an `if` statement based on a different `href` from multiple elements, you need to create an `Array` that implements `forEach`, and select which elements you wish to implement `classList.add()`, as follows:

```
var divs = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("div"));

divs.forEach(function(div) {
  var href = document.querySelector(".a-1").getAttribute("href");
  var location = div.querySelector(".location");

   href = href.split("/");

   if (href.indexOf("c") == 3) {
     location.classList.add("c");
    }
  })
```